# Add if statement or filter if statement in a reactive

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, filtering, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to make a shiny dashboard/app that the user can filter the data on various criteria. Upon applying the filters, the user could choose which variables he/she wants to see in a bar plot as well as a filtered data set.

For the sample code, I want users to be able to filter by location. The levels are Atlanta, Chicago, and Seattle. However, I also want users to be able to filter by ALL cities at once by default. All is not an option in the dataset, so I wanted to add an "All" option. Thus, I want people to filter_if the input$location_type != "All", but I can't get it to work. Below is my code with just the filter--if you could modify it to make the filter_if work, I would be very appreciative!

```
library(tools)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(

  selectInput(inputId = "x",
              label = "Predictor:",
              choices = c("ID", "location", "title", "job_sat", "motivation", "commitment", "review"),
              selected = "ID"),
  selectInput(inputId = "y",
              label = "Outcome:",
              choices = c("ID", "sales", "location", "title", "job_sat", "motivation", "commitment", "review"),
              selected = "sales"),
  textInput(inputId = "plot_title",
            label = "Plot Title:",
            placeholder = "Enter text for this plot's title"),
  selectInput(inputId = "location_type",
              label = "Location:",
              choices = c("All", levels(fakeshinydata$location)),
              selected = "All",
              multiple = TRUE)
),
mainPanel(
  plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  fake_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$location_type)
    dplyr::filter(fakeshinydata, location %in% input$location_type)
   })

   pretty_plot_title <- reactive({toTitleCase(input$plot_title)})

  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data = fake_subset(),
       aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = pretty_plot_title())
    })
}

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need -

```
fake_subset <- reactive({
  req(input$location_type)
  filter(fakeshinydata, (location %in% input$location_type) | (input$location_type == "All"))
})
```